# multiple selection dropdown list not working on a protected excel sheet

Tags: excel, vba, cell, protected, locked

The multiselect doesn't work if the worksheet is protected, even if the actual cell containing the dropdown list is unlocked. It just behaves like a normal data validation list, i.e. the code is ignored.

Is there any way to allow it to work even if the sheet is protected.

It just behaves like a normal data validation list, i.e. the code is ignored. I am expecting to be able to select more than one from the list on a locked spreadsheet.

Comment: Thank you for response. Is there a way i am able to still protect the worksheet and have the code running as it is supposed to?

Answer (score 0):

you can try this code:

ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:="password"

This removes the sheet protection before executing the main code.

To restore protection, at the end of the code, before this line:

exitError:

Add this code:

ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="password"

src : https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/create-multi-select-dropdown-excel/